# Multithread writing to a single file

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using a `BlockingCollection` for my multithread purposes. What I am trying to do is:

1. Scrape some data
2. Export the data to 1 file

#1 works fine, but when I get to #2 the files end up overlapping, so my file ends up like this (this is an example, the exact output order varies):

```
|col 1|col 2|col 1|col 3|col 2|col 1|
```

instead of looking like this:

```
|col 1|col 2|col 3|
|col 1|col 2|col 3|
```

Obviously I am having problem with threads overlapping, but I am not sure how to fix this? This question has already been asked and the proposed solution was to use `lock` and I did try that, <strike>but it did not work.</strike> **EDIT: Using lock works - I had another problem in my code - the "exportString" variable was global, so the same variable was shared between all threads.**

Here is the export code (called by every thread):

```
class ExportClass{
    private Object locker = new Object();
    public void Report(string exportString, string fileLoc){
        lock (locker)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(fileLoc + "\\data.csv", exportString + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `BlockingCollection` code:

```
class Multithreading
{
    BlockingCollection<Action> _taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

    public Multithreading(int workerCount)
    {
        // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Consume);
    }

    public void Dispose() { _taskQ.CompleteAdding(); }

    public void EnqueueTask(Action action) { _taskQ.Add(action); }

    void Consume()
    {
        // This sequence that we’re enumerating will block when no elements
        // are available and will end when CompleteAdding is called. 
        foreach (Action action in _taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            action();     // Perform task.
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't a problem with your line break? You are using \n only... you should use Environment.NewLine (uses a \r\n)

Comment: If you have contention like this, what benefit do you have from using multiple threads to write? You can't ever have more than 1 thread writing at a time, so why not stick with a single threaded solution?

Comment: @EricLemes, I get the exact same result if I used `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @DanielKelley, because 5 threads working at the same time is way faster than 1 thread and time is very important

Comment: What's in your `exportString`, an entire row or just a single *col* ?

Comment: @ScottProkopetz, the actions aren't necessarily atomic, regardless of what is in his `exportString`.  That's one of the "wonderful" thiaboutngs mulprotithreadedgramming. :)

Comment: @dodexahedron but he seems to want to have the actions written sequentially but I don't see anything in his code or the answers that guarantees these actions will be written sequentially -- by nature of the multi-threading, isn't it conceivable that the threads could hit the file in **any** order?

Comment: Right. Serialized transactions are necessary when multithreading access to a single non-thread-safe resource. But it's worse than just having to call things in sequence. If one thread calls `WriteLine("ABC")` and another thread calls `WriteLine("123")`, you still can't predict what result you will get. ABC123 and 123ABC aren't the only two possible results. You could actually end up with A1B2C3 or any other conceivable combination of those characters, or even completely corrupted data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multithreaded file writing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197187/multithreaded-file-writing)

Comment: @dodexahedron, I agree with your answer (and the code that user1723204 supplied) for writing the record, but I believe if he wants to ensure the entire row is written in column order, that he should assemble that record first in some fashion before calling the *Report(..)* method.

Comment: He should, but he also should write to the file on a single thread, as mentioned in my answer, to avoid both the difficulty of multi-threaded file writing and to perform significantly better, anyway.

Comment: @AntonioPetrov Sorry, but I'd dispute that. More threads != better performance (by definition - of course it varies by scenario), and if you have to serialize each write within a lock then that is probably slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `locker` object needs to be static or else multiple instances of the ExportClass will have their own lock objects, completely defeating the purpose of the lock statement.

But, honestly, the answer is not what you're asking for.
The answer is to do your multithreaded work first, storing the results in memory, and then outputting the results in a single thread.  You are actually going SLOWER than that by a significant degree by trying to perform writes to the same file from multiple threads, with locking semantics.

Comment: If each instance is writing to a different file then it's entirely appropriate for them to not be synchronized with each other.  It's not defeating the purpose at all.

Comment: Nope, I am still getting the same result even when the locker is `static`.

Comment: @Servy, the OP is writing to one file - not multiple.

Comment: @AntonioPetrov, see the second portion of my answer. You really shouldn't be doing what you're doing., in the first place.  You're trying to solve a harder problem and producing a slower program in the process.

Comment: @dodexahedron The OP isn't showing the code where he determines what file is written to, so we have *no idea* how many files he's writing to, or whether or not multiple instances will or will not be writing to the same file.

Comment: His question states he's writing to the same file, and his results indicate as much.  And his code does, in fact, show one file name.  If he were writing to different files for each thread, this would not be an issue.

Comment: The question says "Export the data to 1 file" which I interpreted as meaning all threads write to 1 file.

Comment: @dodexahedron, I just tried storing the data into a memory and exporting it after closing all threads, but I still get the same results - displaced data. I will look into the other link you suggested - the producer/consumer solution. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Apparently the problem was that I had defined the `exportString` as a global variable, so it was used by all threads. It all works good now with a `locker`. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

make locker static

```
class ExportClass{
    private static Object locker = new Object();

    public void Report(string exportString, string fileLoc){
        lock (locker)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(fileLoc + "\\data.csv", exportString + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

like dodexahedron said 2 seconds before me